# How to connect to mysql database in digitalocean from windows

Tags: php, mysql, cloud-hosting, mariadb

I am newbie to cloud hosting. My Client has created his domain in digitalocean. He then provided me with the username and password to access the site. Through filezilla I am able to ftp the site with the credentials he had provided. He had also stated MariaDB has been installed for mysql; but I am unable to login to my mysql server. I tried to initiate a mysql connection using the MySQL Workbench but it failed. Would appreciate any help on how I can access the mysql server using my Windows Machine.

Answer (score 1):

This article might be of interest to you: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html